# Python geopandas dataframe of polygons -- determine nearest neighbor polygon?

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically create expanded regions of interest based on polygon geometries in geopandas until some threshold is satisfied (essentially custom regions across the contiguous US).

I have a geopandas dataframe with the following columns:

```
unitspaces_geodf[['unit_space_count', 'city', 'state_code', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'cbsa_code', 'geometry']]
```

where `geometry` is the corresponding polygon for the `cbsa_code` (generated from a shape file).

[image: raw geodataframe]

I can get a total count of `unit_space_count` by grouping the dataframe on `cbsa_code`:

```
unitspaces_geodf.groupby('cbsa_code')['unit_space_count'].sum()
```

[image: groupby]

Based on the `sum()` value of `unit_space_count` in each `cbsa_code` (let's say a threshold of 100) I want to determine the next nearest `geometry` and then combine the two geometries (and concatenate the `cbsa_code`) until `unit_space_count` is above the threshold. This is essentially creating a new neighborhood/region. Then remove these two (or more) `cbsa_code` entries from the pool of available entries to concatenate with.

So in the example above, the last line of the `groupby` clause shows a  `cbsa_code` of `12660` and the total `unit_space_count` is `72`.

For this record, I want to determine the nearest neighbor (using the  `geometry` column and hopefully an out-of-the-box geopandas or shapely method) to generate a new combined `cbsa-code` (something like `12660-12620` if `12620` happened to be the nearest neighbor) and a new `unit_space_count` of 1268 (1196 + 72).

I think I may need to first create a map of all the grouped values to see which regions should be joined with which, but after that I need help with determining how to do these calculations.

Comment: for determine the nearest neighbor, are you thinking the distance from boundary-to-boundary or centroid to centroid?

Comment: @PaulH -- Good question. I hadn't actually thought of that. I would imagine centroid to centroid is easiest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) library to build up a spatial index, which then has a [`nearest`](http://toblerity.org/rtree/tutorial.html#nearest-neighbors) method you can use to get the nearest geometry in the index to any given query. I think Shapely also comes with an rtree implementation which behaves similarly, but I could be wrong - I always use `rtree`. This is probably the fastest way, as it only requires one calculation for each record.

Otherwise, you'll need to compare every geometry to every other one using the shapely `distance` method, and choose the smallest one. I guess in Pandas that would be a full outer join of your dataset to itself, and add a column of distance, and then query out the records where ID's are not equal (implying you calculated the distance to the same polygon) and distance is the shortest.

Comment: Thanks @carusot42! I found a Shapely `rtree` implementation: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#str-packed-r-tree